# Android: getting rid of your sqlite database

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I would to erase and recreate the database for my app each time I send a new version of my app from Eclipse to my phone (I am developing and changing my database very often). What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is something you do not wish to do once it is live, you can just clear data from your application manager each time. Also, you can make the database version number different and have the onUpgrade destroy and recreate the DB

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDbName";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6; 
private static class DbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public DbOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    onUpgrade(this.getWritableDatabase(), 0, 0); 
        // 
    }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL(TableHelper1.CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TableHelper1.TABLE_NAME);

      onCreate(db); 
   }

}
```

Comment: What is the best way to do it in the upgrade function, drop all of the tables and then call the onCreate function?

Comment: You usually have a field in your SQLiteOpenHelper that specifies the db version, and pass that in to the constructor: public SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version). When you're ready to replace the db, just increment the version.

Comment: Pyrodante, please review and accept my edit which makes the database update on every restart. Upon clean install it will unfortunately be created and destroyed twice

Comment: I don't understand your request, I do not see an edit of yours.

Comment: I guess some other user must have gotten rid of it (I'm not exactly sure how the edits need to be approved). Anyway, to make the answer 100% complete add this line after super(..): onUpgrade(this.getWritableDatabase(), 0, 0);

Answer (score 2):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, 1);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {   
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE USERS (username TEXT, password TEXT);");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERS");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

i use this one in my code :) change super(context, dbName, null, <database version number>); and it will execute onUpgrade method.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go into Debug Configurations, then Android Application on the left hand side. Select the debug configuration that you are using and then select the Target tab.

At the bottom, you'll see a checkbox labeled "Wipe User Data".

If you check that, everytime you launch the simulator, the data associated with your application (including the SQLite database) will be erased.

Your application will then call onCreate() for your SQLiteOpenHelper, and your database will be recreated.

Comment: This isn't preferable, as one would have to restart the emulator, which is certainly more time-consuming than just updating the version. And it doesn't apply to debugging on the phone rather than the emulator.